# D3.js V4 Zoom not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm using D3 v4 and Datamaps in my angular project.
I try to make the zoom working but I have no clue what's the problem.

I have a function that creates the map:

```
public createChart() {
    this.geoChart = new Datamap({
      element: this.geolocationChart.nativeElement,
      scope: 'world',
      width: null,
      height: null,
      projection: 'mercator',
      responsive: true,
      geographyConfig: {
        hideAntarctica: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderOpacity: 1,
        borderColor: '#ffffff',
        popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
          return ['<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>', geo.properties.name, ': ' + data.countryData, '</strong></div>'].join('');
        },
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: true,
        highlightFillColor: '#ff4200',
        highlightBorderWidth: 2,
        highlightBorderOpacity: 1
      },
      fills: {
        defaultFill: '#f5f5f5',
        highlight: '#5005a0'
      },
      data: this.convertData(this.defaultCountryData),
      done: function(datamap) {
        datamap.svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', redraw));
        function redraw() {
          datamap.svg.selectAll('g').attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

I trigger it in ngAfterContentInit.

When I try to use the mouse wheel to zoom or drag the map, I receive this error message in the console:
"Cannot read property 'button' of null"

I'm importing D3 and Datamaps like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import Datamap from 'datamaps/dist/datamaps.world.min.js';
```

I'm really clueless what could be the problem. I've seen other posts and everyone mentioned to import D3 just like I did. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after more research I write this code:

```
function(datamap) {
        d3.select('.datamap').call(
          d3
            .zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.7, 6])
            .on('zoom', function() {
              datamap.svg.selectAll('g').attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
            })
        );
      }
```

It runs after the chart has loaded, and fortunately it works. For some reason when you call the zoom() function on the datamap.svg it cause an error while datamap.svg and d3.select('.datamap') creates a similar array but d3.select create a selection. If anyone know why it doesn't work the other way please explain it.